# ANOVA in with n-dimensional observations?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am starting to work with ANOVA in R for the following case: 35 countries have scores between [0,1] in 120 dimensions. Through a certain criteria I have them previously separated in 8 groups (1 to 8). These are all stored in data.frame "datos" which has the columns: dimension, country, value, group.
I am able to do ANOVA for each of these 120 dimensions through:

```
for(i in 1:120){
  L=datos$dimension==rownames(dim1[i,]) #dim1 is a matrix that has the order of the dimensions I use.
  pivot<-datos[L,] #dataset with only the data of dimension i
  aovresult<-aov(value~group, data=pivot) #do ANOVA on dimension i based on groups
  p_value[i]<-summary(aovresult)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]] #extract the p_value
}
p_value<-as.data.frame(cbind(rownames(dim1[i,]),p_value))
colnames(p_value)<-c("dimension","p_value")
```

As you see, the matrix p_value has the p_values of the ANOVA for each dimension. Now, I want to know how can I do an ANOVA for all dimensions at the *same* time, since I know that the original grouping (1 to 8) is based on all of them together.

This is an open problem, so any advice is welcomed.

Comment: This logical expression `data$dimension==rownames(dim[i,])` produces ... exactly what? (It looks terribly wrong to me but maybe you have done something I don't understand.)

Comment: Hi, it returns a logical vector of the same length as data that says in which rows you find the dimension with the name dim[i,]. The code in general works to get 120 ANOVAs but I just want one of the full set.

Comment: Looks pretty tortured. Would be clearer if you mad a much smaller data example with say 5 columns. It also would be a lot clearer if you used object names that were not function names (data, dim). You should also stop using `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`. It will coerce all your p-values to factors, creating confusing errors in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I recently started working with R. I changed the names so its clearer, but is the question clear? I need to know if it is possible to do one ANOVA for all dimensions and see if these countries are of the same population or not. let me know if i need to explain more.

Comment: It sounds as though you should be looking at the p-value for group. If that is not enough, then it sounds as though you want to do a principal components analysis rather than anova. The goals of this effort still seem vague and I think you really should take what you have here and move the question over to CrossValidated.com to get better statistical strategy in hand before proceeding with further R coding.

Comment: Thanks, I will post it there. I can't seem to find the way to move it directly though. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're looking for a M(ultiple)ANOVA